# Trying to insert numeric info in database

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert a number in a field of my sql database. The table is:

```
Create table IF NOT EXISTS LJugador(
Fecha date,
vm int,
totalpuntos int,
nom_jugador varchar(80),
FOREIGN KEY (nom_jugador) REFERENCES Jugadores(nombre),
PRIMARY KEY(Fecha, nom_jugador)
)engine=innodb;
```

The PHP code for insert:

```
$ljuga_in = "INSERT INTO ljugador VALUE( now(), '{$jugadores[$m][2]}','{$jugadores[$m][3]}', '{$jugadores[$m][1]}' )";
```

when I do echo of `$ljuga_in` to see if it is being inserted correctly, I get:

```
INSERT INTO ljugador VALUE( now(), '4.130.000','92', 'Osman' );
```

You can see the number is being inserted correctly, but when I make a select query to see the information, VM has `4130` - the last three zeros are not there.

The field is `int`, but I have tried with numeric and double or float and nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try using DECIMAL(n, p) where n is the overall number of digits and p the number of digits after the comma, so e.g. for DECIMAL(10, 2) the maximum that can be represented would be 99.999.999,99